# MessageBox cuts off text on \0 character

Tags: c#

I have this string (which is derived from a serial port)

```
string dataincoming = 
  " 10\0/\0 17\0/\0 2016\0,\0 16\0:\0 59\0:\0 50\0,\0  51.1,\0   0.2,\0 1,\0 0,\0\r";
MessageBox.Show(dataincoming);
```

But the messagebox displays '10'

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try this to fix string : dataincoming = string.Join("", dataincoming.Split(new char[] {'\0', '\r', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

Answer (score 2):

the character `\0` is a null character, it it will stop showing the text there

if you want to show it, you have to add `@"text"`

you can add this helper method

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static string RemoveNullCharacter(this string str)
    {
        return str.Replace("\0", "");
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
MessageBox.Show(dataincoming.RemoveNullCharacter());
```

Comment: ok - so how do i fix this ? It should come out like this " 10/ 17/ 2016, 17:  6: 50,  50.9,   0.2, 1, 0,"

Comment: You could argue that since it will show more data in the console that this is actually a bug in MessageBox API. \0 is a valid character in .NET strings.

Comment: the message box api calls out to the win32 api so theres no fixing that.

Comment: @mikez see Daniel for why

Comment: @Fredou Presumably the calling the Console also calls a Win32 API call at some point, so I don't see why that should make a difference.

Comment: @mikez create a question asking why and how this doesn't behave the same, it is out of context here

Answer (score 1):

Replace null-terminator to some symbol (space):

```
dataincoming = dataincoming.Replace('\0', ' ');
```

Comment: this will remove a null character to add an space character, not sure if that is what is wanted